# in mac OS X, how to use popupbuttoncell like this

Tags: macos

[image]

I want to use popupbuttoncell like this. I don't know how to play it.

Just use these?

- `attachPopUpWithFrame:inView:`
- `dismissPopUp`
- `performClickWithFrame:inView:`

Answer (score 0):

A NSPopUpButtonCell is what automatically goes inside a [NSPopUpButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPopUpButton), which is what you *really* want to display and make use of.

You can set up a NSPopUpButton in your storyboard or XIB file, or you can do it programatically.

[Here is Apple's documentation on how to do it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ManagingPopUpItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000274-BAJDEEJA), and [here is a tutorial that talks about it as well](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27388/core-controls-in-mac-os-x-part-12).

Comment: can you give an example? but i want to use it like Calendar.app in mac

Comment: Yes, Apple has [example source code available for you that can be downloaded here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/MenuMadness/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008870-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).  Look for the "Download Sample Code" button near the top of the page.

Comment: no,but i don't want this,just when the mouse move to the popupbutto,then it show the popupbuttoncell,when the mouse move from th popupbutton,it just show a title